# Command Line PHP - Is it Thread Safe?

Tags: php, multithreading, thread-safety, command-line-interface

The title says it all.

I have read several stackoverflow questions with regards to Apache/Nginx/etc, where the question mostly focuses on thread safety between PHP and the web server. However I would just like to run PHP at the command line; in this case, is it thread safe?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but by virtue of the fact that it is running as a single thread when run from the command line. Thread Safety is more relevant when PHP is run as an Apache Module where it is runing in a multi thread environment

Comment: What about if I start several threads in my php script?